# any rss feed lib for gae

Tags: google-app-engine, rss, feed

i want enable rss for gae on my site .

and did you know the simple way to do this  ?

thanks

this is a example i searched:

```
class FeedHandler(BaseRequestHandler):
    def get(self,tags=None):
        blogs = Weblog.all().filter('entrytype =','post').order('-date').fetch(10)
        last_updated = datetime.datetime.now()
        if blogs and blogs[0]:
            last_updated = blogs[0].date
            last_updated = last_updated.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")
        for blog in blogs:
            blog.formatted_date = blog.date.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/atom+xml'
        self.generate('atom.xml',{'blogs':blogs,'last_updated':last_updated})
```

any more simple  ?

Comment: It's not helpful to just copy code from some other codebase, without any context about what the other codebase uses it for. For example, what does `self.generate()` do? The code you've copied here just sets the last updated time and formats dates, it doesn't generate any RSS itself.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look to [PyRSS2Gen](http://www.dalkescientific.com/Python/PyRSS2Gen.html).
You could find many examples of self-made python blogs on Google appengine that generate RSS 2.0 feed using PyRSS2Gen.
[Here](http://jamesgae.appspot.com/blog/2009/12/28/beginners-guide-on-setting-up-your-own-blog-on-gae-part-2) and [Here](http://code.google.com/p/tublog/source/browse/trunk/tublog.py) some good examples.